# How to replace Ubuntu host with Windows 7 installed in a virtual machine?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I have installed Windows 7 Using VirtualBox in Ubuntu.

I want my primary Operating system as Windows 7.

Please guide me how to uninstall/delete Ubuntu

Comment: See the link for the guide to uninstall Ubuntu and install Windows: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Answer (score 1):

Because Windows is in VirtualBox, you can't remove the Ubuntu operating system, as it's the host OS for the guest VirtualBox OS.

You'd have to install Windows to the hard drive, wiping the system totally in the process, in order to use Windows 7 as your primary OS.  IF you've already used your activation key, Microsoft might have a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay you will need a dvd or usb stick with a windows 7 iso on it. Firstly boot into windows on your machine. Then press the start button and search for disc management (It should be called create or edit partition or something).

Find your ubuntu partition, right click it and press delete. Then extend the volume of your windows partition. If you restart now you will get a grub boot error.

Boot into that dvd or usb with the windows 7 iso, click install, then there should be a advanced option or something. Click cmd prompt and type "bootrec /fixmbr" and "bootrec /fixboot" without quotation marks. If you did it correctly it should just boot into windows and your ubuntu partition will be gone.

It's sad to see you go but I'm sure you have your reasons. Good luck!